# Is there an API to fetch all public categories in GCP AI Hub

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, client-server

I am trying to fetch data assets from AI Hub using an API. I looked for java client libraries in [AI Hub documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-hub/docs) but I didn't find anything. Is there any other external java client libraries to fetch these data assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official client library for AI Hub yet as it is in beta feature and in development currently. 
Nevertheless, you can fetch the data assets with Google Cloud Platform using Data Catalog [1]. Data Catalog is also in beta release but it has already implemented its own Client Library for java [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/concepts/introduction-data-catalog#using_data_catalog

[2] https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/libraries

Answer (score 0):

Data Catalog is now GA and you are able to use the search API to fetch your data assets. You will be able to search for the built-in assets - at the time of this writing, Big Query and Pub Sub assets are automatically ingested. You are also able to use the custom types API, to ingest other assets, like the ones from AI Hub, then you would be able to search for it in Data Catalog.

[Search Java Client Library Docs](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/how-to/search#data-catalog-how-to-search-java)

[Custom Types API Docs](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/how-to/custom-entries)